# You don't have permission to access /nagios/ on this server

Tags: apache, nagios, graphite

I have been trying to setup nagios on mac and it definitely seems pretty easy but I am stuck at this point - I am unable to load the `localhost/nagios/` page. I have the right configuration as far as I think.

I have installed PHP and changed the httpd.conf to include "index.php" with index.html. I do not think there is more to it but this small thing is not letting me proceed.

Could anyone shed some light and show me the way?

This is what I have in my configuration file for nagios in hhtpd.conf for apache:

#
Nagios stuff

ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin/ "/opt/local/sbin/nagios/"

< Directory "/opt/local/sbin/nagios">

AllowOverride None

```
Options ExecCGI
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthName "Nagios Access"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /opt/local/etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
require valid-user
```

< /Directory>

Alias /nagios "/opt/local/share/nagios"

< Directory "/opt/local/share/nagios">

```
Options None
AllowOverride AuthConfig
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

< /Directory>

#
 End Nagios stuff

-- And the error_log file for apache has this:

[Fri Oct 19 11:02:09 2012] [error] [client ::1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /opt/local/share/nagios/

Answer (score 16):

To resolve this problem:

1. Simply install '**PHP**' on your Nagios Server.
   `yum install php.i686` if your OS is 32-bit or `yum install php.x86_64` if your OS is 64-bit
2. After the php installation **restart** your **Apache/httpd** server. `service httpd restart`

Answer (score 1):

you will have to change the nagios folder permission in your apache configuration. Look for nagios configuration file in apache (probably conf.d or extra folder).

[Check here](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-nagios-in-rhel-centos-fedora/)

Comment: I just added what I have in my configuration file to my post and I am not sure how to change the permission from that? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I could get to localhost/nagios by commenting the Options line - not sure what that means? But I am working on getting to this page now - http://localhost/nagios/cgi-bin/    For some reason, this would't show up even after I remove the Options line

Comment: Have you created a user for nagios already? create one and use it for login on the nagios application. Also create a new group (unix user group i meant) and add both nagios user and apache user to this group. Use this same group while configuring nagios.

Comment: I did those stuff and I could get to the /localhost/nagios page without a user (removed that part). But unable to go past that but anyway, I am bypassing this step to directly make nagios communicate with Graphite to send alert emails.

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea about graphite.